# How to position tooltips on top of date selection using datepicker in ui-bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a view where I would like to provide some tool tips to users based on the dates that they select on the datepicker. I can easily add tooltips to the datepicker, but that gets positioned on top of the datepicker as a whole.

In index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>
    <h4>Inline</h4>
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:400px;">
      <datepicker ng-model="dt" tooltip="{{dynamicMsg}}" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In example.js:

```
  $scope.$watch('dt', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    var today = new Date($scope.events[0].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var dayToCheck = new Date(newVal).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (today === dayToCheck) {
      $scope.dynamicMsg = 'Room Unavailable';
    } else {
      $scope.dynamicMsg = 'Room Available';
    }
  });
```

See Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/qk7AXWJdkm3wB74JoaLw?p=preview

What I would like to do is to position the tooltip exactly on top of the date that the user chooses, rather than how it shows up on the plunker. I am guessing some funky CSS tricks should help here, but I am unable to think of how this once can be done? Will appreciate any help from the community. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

**Step One**: Implement Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker in your app. If you run into any issues, post code in a new question regarding your attempt at implementing datepicker.

**Step Two**: Implement bootstrap tooltips.  If you run into any issues, post code in a new question regarding your attempt at implementing tooltips.

**Step Three**: Implement tooltips in your datepicker.  If you run into any issues, post code in a new question regarding your attempt at implementing integration between tooltips and datepicker.

Comment: smart alec response! :) Okay so I am way into Step Three, what I wanted was to show the tool tip positioned on top of each date button press. I've modified my question to reflect this.